# laravel 8 bootstrap не компилируется

Tags: laravel

скачал архив с файлами bootstap 5 кинул resources/css/bootstrap.css
и в resources/js/bootstrap.js

css скомпилировался а js нет

ERROR in ./resources/js/bootstrap.js 59:141-166
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@popperjs/core' in 'W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\resources\js'

ERROR in ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@popperjs/core' in 'W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\resources\js'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\РОМАН\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-16T12_27_22_995Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\РОМАН\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-16T12_27_23_063Z-debug.log
PS W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka>

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
mix.copyDirectory('resources/img', 'public/img');
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm i @popperjs/core --save-dev`

у меня все заработало ответ нашел на англ [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905662/npm-warnings-when-installing-laravel-bootstrap)